# Get cmake and home-brew to work together

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

When I install libraries with homebrew cmake can't seem to find them. Is there a simple way to fix this for an arbitrary library installed with brew.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Default

By default brew's libraries installed to `/usr/local/lib` folder:

```
> ls /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib@
```

Check that this path exists in [CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH) variable. In this case
find is trivial:

```
message("system: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH}")
find_library(LZMA_LIBRARY lzma)
message("lzma: ${LZMA_LIBRARY}")
```

Result:

```
system: /usr/local;/usr;/;...
lzma: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib
```

#### Otherwise

If it is not you need to modify [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) or [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH)
before [find_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_library) command:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local)
```

Comment: Note: for me the path was /opt/homebrew/lib